# no office 2010 application will start

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-outlook

Vista Home Premium 32-bit and OFFICE 2010.
As soon as I start an application I get an error.

Outlook gives me a side-by-side configuration problem. Word or any other application tells me the there is not associated prgram.

All these problems suddenly occurred after an automated update.

I was advised to download a MV C++ 2005 program, what didn't do anything.  Another told me to perform a restore to a date before the automated update. This to didn't do anything.  I'm runnng out of options and out of good humor. 
Is there nobody who can help? Why is this happening anyway.

Comment: Please can you post the exact wording of the errors, or better still a screen-shot of the errors?

Answer (score 0):

First I'd try to repair the Office installation, then I'd try to reinstall. If those failed, I'd remove Office entirely (be sure to back up those Outlook files) and reinstall cleanly.